# Different types in a single shared memory

Tags: c++, c, shared-memory

What is the best way to store a uint32_t, uint8_t in the shared memory in continuous successions?
i.e. if we represent `uint32_t` as `a` and `uint8_t` as `b`, i want to store it in shared memory as

`ababababababababababababab`

what is the best way to do this? should I use void* and then typecast it each time i write something to shared memory? Or is there a simpler way? 
will Typecasting create complications when I want to travese the shared memory lateron?

Comment: struct, perhaps, or a union, depending on whether or not they'll always appear as a pair or not. you're going to get some gaps due to alignment either way, though, if that was your goal.

Comment: You should define what you mean by *best*. Best can be easier to maintain, more compact in memory or more efficient, and the different goals might lead to different approaches. Also, do you really need them to be interleaved?

Comment: i dont want to lose space due to alignment. that is why i want to avoid structures.

Comment: best in this case is compact in memory.

Comment: Surely, your compiler supports some pragma or attrib that packs a struct?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan: And you know the effect that this will have on your program (probable slower performance), non-atomic writes to memory for unaligned in32 (assuming intel arch)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of a packed struct sounds like a good bet, no casting needed.

Comment: Oh, it's shared memory, OK, a pointer to an array of packed struct, then.  So much the better - you can declare it any size you want, (within reason).

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan: That's the point of the answer: if the structure is **packed**: *you won't*.

Comment: I think this answer would be so much more useful if it explained what 'packed structs' are. Somebody who asks a question because he worries about losing space due to alignment of fields in a struct won't recognize the term "packed".

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - Googling for 'packed struct' gives the 'Data structure alignment' Wikipedia entry as the first hit.  Packing is explained there.  The problem with explaining 'packed struct' myself is that I may get it wrong :)

Comment: @MartinJames: Yeah, I know (I googled for it myself). Many people on SO actually quote other sources (say, Wikipedia) and then post a link to the full article.

Answer (score 1):

If you must pack the data, then the obvious thing is to use implementation-specific pragmas to pack a structure, thereby avoiding padding. If you don't want to do that (why not?), then something like this would do:

```
typedef uint8_t (*Thingy)[sizeof(uint32_t) + 1];

static inline uint32_t read_a(Thingy t) {
    uint32_t val;
    memcpy(&val, t, sizeof(uint32_t));
    return val;
}

static inline void write_b(Thingy t, uint8_t val) {
    reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(t)[sizeof(uint32_t)] = val;
}
```

And the obvious for `write_a` and `read_b`.

Starting from those four snippets, you can make things more object-y in C++ according to taste. I've typed `Thingy` as a pointer-to-array so that `++` and `+ n` do what you'd expected from an iterator, but you can't just assign to `*thingy` as you would with an iterator. You could just as well write a class that keeps a `uint8_t*` data member, overload the necessary operators to achieve the same thing, and then read and write via member functions or maybe proxy objects.

For what it's worth, the fact that `uint8_t` exists implies that necessarily `sizeof(uint32_t) == 4`. So if you have some constant from elsewhere, like `#define PACKED_THINGY_SIZE 5`, then you can use it portably.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared memory segment with the size of `sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)` and store each value after the other:

```
memcpy(shm, &a, sizeof(a));
memcpy(shm + sizeof(a), &b, sizeof(b));
```